# Dialog within Popover in React HeadlessUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, headless-ui

I have a navbar that uses HeadlessUI's `Popover` on mobile for the hamburger menu. By default, this menu closes when you click out/focus on an element that is not in it.

Now I'm trying to add a modal (HeadlessUI `Dialog`) that I want to open when clicking on a button that is in the popover menu. The modal is used within a `ModalButton` component definition (`<><button><dialog></>`). This is done for separation of concerns (everything relating to the modal is within `ModalButton`).

The issue is: when I'm in the navbar's popover menu and click on the button to open the dialog. The browser focuses on this new dialog, and so the popover loses focus, making it close. Since it closed, the button (and thus the dialog sibling) are no longer rendered, and so the dialog disappears instantly.

For reference, this is a pseudocode of the react tree:

```
<navbar>
  <popover>
    <>            {/* "ModalButton" containing both the button and the dialog */}
      <button />  {/* Button that opens the dialog */}
      <dialog />  {/* This uses a portal internally (with HeadlessUI) */}
    </>
  </popover>
</navbar>
```

I can think of a few ways to solve this but neither are very good:

1. Pull the modal higher in the tree, outside of the popover/hamburger menu but still inside the navbar. But that breaks separation of concerns since the navbar now has to worry about the open state of the modal.
2. Put the modal somewhere at the top of the tree, and use some kind of global state (requires a state management library) to handle the opening of the modal.
3. Maybe there's a way to prevent the `Popover` from closing when focusing on the dialog? (but still allow it to close when focusing anything that is not the dialog)

I'd love to hear any ideas on fixing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the dialog higher up in the tree. Usually these can go at the page level, or even the app level, depending on how global these dialogs are.

You can then use your favourite global state manager or the `useContext` hook to tell these dialogs to open programmatically from anywhere in your app.

In which case the popover closing automatically shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: That's what I ended up going for, thanks! It just feels a bit clunky to have a dialog for a small/specific part of the website be so high up in the tree.

Comment: @PandawanFr usually that's where dialogs live. The only reason HeadlessUI can put them deeper in the hierarchy is because of the use of portals. However, in this case, the popover closing when it loses focus overrides even that.

Comment: @Soviut Doing this causes another issue - when a popover and dialog are both opened, clicking away closes the popover first. The workaround that I am using is to always manually close a popover when I am opening the dialog from within the popover. This ensures that there won't be a case where both popover and dialog are opened. Any idea how does headlessui prioritise which to close first whenever a user clicks away?